# How to create a Toast from a class

Tags: android

I have a new project - MyProject.  In that project I have the class `MyProject` and another class `uTorrent`.  How do I show a toast from the uTorrent class?  When I try this:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

I get this error:

> The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type uTorrent

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The post seems to be old, but I'm posting this answer in case someone is having the same issue

Answer:

You need to extend the class, as follows:

```
package HelloAndroid.workspace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myClass **extends Activity**{

......

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a Context into the class you're using the Toast.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make a public function in you activity like this :

in Activity.Class :

```
public void makeToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

then call from uTorrent.class :

```
activity.makeToast(e.getMessage());
```

But it suppose you gave the activity as a parameter to uTorrent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this from an Activity?  It would help to see some code, but what you need is a Context.  This will typically be your Activity or Application class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the class a Context variable with the context where you want to show the Toast.

Anyway i guess that djg have the correct answer